# Read Multiple Properties File using spring profiles in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am trying to load 2 properties file in spring boot.
One of them contains the metadata (Database connection and other such properties). The other contains business logic (mapping between upstream and downstream Entity. This mapping is different in Dev and Prod, hence can't have a single resource file for these).

I want to use Spring Profiles for different environments (Dev, Stage, Prod).
So, I created 3 different folders in `src/main/resources` 1 for each environment.
Using spring profies, I am aware how to have env specific application-env.properties file. However, I am unable to move forward on how to use the same for my use case.

PS : Not adding any code snippet, because the question doesn't require one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.5/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files):

```shell
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=\
    optional:classpath:/default.properties,\
    optional:classpath:/override.properties
```

You could also define this in your code before starting Spring Boot:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "optional:classpath:/default.properties,optional:classpath:/override.properties");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

---

To use custom prefixes for your app specific properties you can define `@ConfigurationProperties` class(es):

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.mapper")
public class MapperProperties {

    private String foo;
}
```

and use it in any component:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class YourComponent {
    
    private final MapperProperties properties;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using "spring.config.location" and passing multiple property files, can I have custom propertyKeys for each of the resource? 
Ex : app.mapper = "dev/mapper.properties", app.config="dev/application.properties"?
I ask this because the mapper is parsed and loaded into a Properties object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve… all keys from all locations are merged together to form a single configuration.